# Cache Django REST Framework HTTP Streaming Response?

Tags: python, django, caching, httpresponse

I am trying to cache Django REST Framework HTTP streaming responses.

My thinking is a Response sub-class can write the chunks into a temporary file as it streams, and on closing after streaming the final chunk, run a callable that copies the file into cache.

```py
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

class CachedStreamingHttpResponse(StreamingHttpResponse):

    def __init__(self, streaming_content=(), *args, **kwargs):
        self._post_render_callbacks = []
        self._buffer = None
        self.buffered = False
        super().__init__(streaming_content, *args, **kwargs)

    def _set_streaming_content(self, value):
        self._buffer = TemporaryFile()
        super()._set_streaming_content(value)

    def post_render(self):
        self._buffer.seek(0)
        self.buffered = self._buffer
        retval = self
        for post_callback in self._post_render_callbacks:
            newretval = post_callback(retval)
            if newretval is not None:
                retval = newretval

    def buffer(self, b):
        self._buffer.write(b)
        return b

    @staticmethod
    def closing_iterator_wrapper(iterable, close):
        try:
            yield from iterable
        finally:
            close()

    @property
    def streaming_content(self):
        buffered = map(self.buffer, super().streaming_content)
        return self.closing_iterator_wrapper(buffered, self.post_render)

    @streaming_content.setter
    def streaming_content(self, value):
        self._set_streaming_content(value)

    def add_post_render_callback(self, callback):
        """A list of callables to be run after the final chunk is returned. Used to copy the response to cache."""
        if self.buffered:
            callback(self)
        else:
            self._post_render_callbacks.append(callback)
```

I plan to have my cache framework pass a callable into the response, which then calls it from a content_stream `finally` block to copy the temporary file into S3.

However with the above code I see *two* streams - one compressed, one not, and the response cannot be returned from cache.

I have modified this question to save the reader reading about syntax errors, but one was interesting. Because I overrode the `streaming_content` getter, I had to re-declare the setter (identically to how it was declared in the super-class).

Footnote: Caching streams is almost always wrong. But these responses are generated by complex queries and DRF serializers and viewsets, and we stream so our many users on very poor connections see data arriving more quickly. Given a stream locks resources on server and client for the duration, this might use more resources than not streaming; it might push some memory consumption to the database rather than webserver as records are cursored. The responses are up to a few megabytes, usually less, and these will be cached on our S3 cache tier. Redis would be too expensive.

Comment: The main idea of a streamed response is that these are typically large, even *huge* and often do not fit in memory. A typical use case is video. So usually it is very undesirable to cache these. Since it would blow up memory.

Comment: Thanks, yes some of these responses are a few megabytes and we pull a few rows from the database at a time to keep memory usage down, although the main reason we stream is time to first byte (given a stream keeps a gunicorn worker alive I suspect it doesn't save much in hardware terms). This code streams chunk at a time to a temporary file though, so only the generator's file reference stays in memory, I think. These resources are expensive to generate, and this cache tier is S3-backed so storage is cheap.

Comment: Found a couple bugs. First dumb one - I didn't pass `streaming_content` up to `super().init`. Second one is more interesting. `StreamingHttpResponse` defines a `@setter`. Because I override the property _getter_ here, I need to re-implement the setter. I assume this is because Python needs to decorate the final implementation of the getter, but I'm not sure, as [apparently (5th comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183512/1308967) actually you needn't use the right property name in `@streaming_content.setter`. I've updated the code in the question, still working on the caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth repeating Willem's warning above. In almost all cases, you should not cache streams. nginx even by default consumes any stream and returns non-streamed. Streams lock up resources on client and server for the duration. You typically stream because there is a lot of data, and so you don't want to wait until it is all generated in memory before sending it to the client - to save memory, and/or so the client starts receiving data earlier. A cache often loads data into memory as part of storing it, removing both advantages and flooding your RAM and cache storage. And large responses are often coming from storage, such as video, so there's no benefit from caching. However, I was working on an aged, unwisely built project with far bigger issues, unwilling to overturn a decade-old decision to support streaming. I decided to keep my gunpowder dry to fight bigger fires..

The reason for getting two streams turned out to be `GZipMiddleware`.

`StreamingHttpResponse` applies `make_bytes` in the `streaming_content` getter, by returning `map(self.make_bytes, self._iterator)`. I used the same approach to apply `buffer` and the save_to_cache callback.

`GZipMiddleware` however, just replaces `streaming_content`:

```py
response.streaming_content = compress_sequence(response.streaming_content)
```

The `streaming_content` setter calls `_set_streaming_content`, which replaces `self._iterator`. So `CachedStreamingHttpResponse._iterator` now contains the original content, but with the calls to `self.make_bytes`, `self.buffer` `self.closing_iterator_wrapper`, and now GZip's `compress_sequence`, baked in.

When streaming, the `StreamingHttpResponse.streaming_content` getter still calls `make_bytes` on each GZipped chunk from `self._iterator`, again. `make_bytes` is harmless, but `CachedHttpStreamingResponse` also applies `buffer` and `close` a second time, hence seeing two streams.

The below code resolves this by replacing `_iterator`, like GZipMiddleware, instead of applying the generators at fetch time.

Should GZipMiddleware be changed to better align with `StreamingHttpResponse`? Perhaps `StreamingHttpResponse` should maintain a list of callables to be called on each chunk? imo that would be a clearer API which might encourage more middleware to support streaming responses. But smooth deprecation would be tricky.

```py
class CachedStreamingHttpResponse(StreamingHttpResponse):

    def __init__(self, streaming_content=(), *args, **kwargs):
        self._post_render_callbacks = []
        self.buffered = False
        self._buffer = TemporaryFile()
        super().__init__(streaming_content, *args, **kwargs)
        # Replace self._iterator here, rather than wrap super().streaming_content, so methods are applied once only:
        buffered_stream = map(self.buffer, super().streaming_content)
        self.streaming_content = self.closing_iterator_wrapper(buffered_stream, self.post_render)

    def post_render(self):
        self._buffer.seek(0)
        self.buffered = self._buffer
        retval = self
        for post_callback in self._post_render_callbacks:
            newretval = post_callback(retval)
            if newretval is not None:
                retval = newretval

    def buffer(self, b):
        self._buffer.write(b)
        return b

    @staticmethod
    def closing_iterator_wrapper(iterable, close):
        try:
            yield from iterable
        finally:
            close()

    def add_post_render_callback(self, callback):
        """A list of callables to be run after the final chunk is returned. Used to copy the response to cache."""
        if self.buffered:
            callback(self)
        else:
            self._post_render_callbacks.append(callback)
```

Couple more steps - our caching framework caches whole responses, rather than just the content, so we need to construct a response that won't be streamed when it comes from cache.

```py
class CachedStreamingHttpResponse(StreamingHttpResponse):
    """
    A streaming HTTP response class that also spools the stream to disk for caching.
    """

    def __init__(self, streaming_content=(), *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(streaming_content, *args, **kwargs)

        # Initialize working variables

        # Callables to run after completion - used to run cache_set callback
        self._post_render_callbacks = []
        # True once the full stream has been streamed
        self._complete = False

        # Stream is streamed to this file as it is streamed to client, so that large responses do not consume RAM.
        # It is critical these temporary files are tidied up promptly. Under Unix, the directory entry for the file
        # is either not created at all or is removed immediately after the file is created.
        # Additionally, file.close() is called:
        #   - when self._resource_closers are run in HttpResponseBaseResponse.close(), which is called by the WSGI server
        #   - when the TemporaryFile object is garbage collected, or
        #   - by CachedStreamingResponse.get_cacheable_response, when constructing a response to pickle and cache
        self._buffer = TemporaryFile()

        # Write each chunk to the temporary file as it is streamed:
        buffered_stream = map(self.buffer, super().streaming_content)
        # Call post_render after the stream finishes, to call the cache_set callback:
        self.streaming_content = self.closing_iterator_wrapper(buffered_stream, self.post_render)
        # Note: We set streaming_content, rather than have streaming_content wrap on return like StreamingHttpResponse, 
        # because that's how GZipMiddleware works. If we don't, GZipMiddleware applies the generators twice.
        # Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76181779/

    def buffer(self, b: bytes):
        self._buffer.write(b)
        return b

    @property
    def buffered(self):
        if self._complete:
            return self._buffer

    def post_render(self):
        self._buffer.seek(0)
        self._complete = True
        retval = self
        for post_callback in self._post_render_callbacks:
            newretval = post_callback(retval)
            if newretval is not None:
                retval = newretval

    def add_post_render_callback(self, callback: callable):
        """A list of callables to be run after the final chunk is returned. Used to copy the response to cache."""
        if self.buffered:
            callback(self)
        else:
            self._post_render_callbacks.append(callback)

    @staticmethod
    def closing_iterator_wrapper(iterable, close: callable):
        try:
            yield from iterable
        finally:
            close()

    def construct_cacheable_response(self):
        if self.buffered is False:
            raise ValueError("Cannot construct a cacheable response until the stream has completed.")

        response = HttpResponse(content=self.buffered.read())
        self.buffered.close()

        # content is cached before encoding (eg, gzip) and session cookie are applied by middleware
        response.headers = {k: v for k, v in self.headers.items() if k != "Content-Encoding"}
        return response
```

We then need to connect it to our cache decorator:

```py
if isinstance(result, CachedStreamingHttpResponse):

    def cache_stream(streaming_response: CachedStreamingHttpResponse) -> None:
        # Next time this URL is called, return HttpResponse from the S3 cache tier without streaming
        cache.set(cache_key, streaming_response.construct_cacheable_response(), _timeout)

    result.add_post_render_callback(cache_stream)
```

Important to note that this does load the full response into RAM very briefly when writing to cache and reading from it (because the Django cache API unfortunately doesn't allow for streaming), so this is only suitable when the response is a few megabytes max.